# Amazon website shows "Deliver to Country". How can I change it programmatically in Python Selenium to take screenshots

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

The problem:
I want to search keywords on Amazon and take screenshots. I am using selenium package. However, when I search on amazon.co.uk, it shows delivery address as Unites States. How can I change the "Deliver to Country"?

Below are sample Python code and a sample screenshot.

```
import time as t
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=UA")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") 
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=2160x3840')

urls = ['https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=advil', 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=Whitening toothpaste']

def get_secondly_screenshots(navi_dictionary):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)

    driver.get('https://www.amazon.co.uk')
    driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='50%'")
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        test = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="sp-cc-rejectall-link"]')
        test.click()
        print('gotcha!')

    except:
        pass

    now = datetime.now()
    date_time = now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
    sh_url = url.split('?k=')[1]
    print(sh_url, date_time)
    driver.save_screenshot(f'{sh_url}_{date_time}.png')

    print('screenshotted ', url)

    t.sleep(2)
    driver.quit()
for url in urls:    
    get_secondly_screenshots(url)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to set UK delivery address on UK Amazon when your IP address is out from the UK you can do the following steps:

1. Open the "Delivery to" dialog
2. Insert some valid UK postal code and click submit button
3. Approve this on the appeared after that pop-up.
4. As you asked, I also added the code to close cookies banner and click "continue".
   The following Selenium code performs that

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

url = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=advil"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'nav-global-location-popover-link'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-action='GLUXPostalInputAction']"))).send_keys("PO16 7GZ")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[aria-labelledby='GLUXZipUpdate-announce']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".a-popover-footer #GLUXConfirmClose"))).click()
time.sleep(1)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".glow-toaster-footer input[data-action-type='DISMISS']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "sp-cc-accept"))).click()
```

The result of this code is

[image]
In case you have any questions about my code - don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thank you. How can I click the continue button on the top left and also accept the cookies?

Comment: OK, I added that too

Comment: Thanks. It fails when using it with amazon.fr. Does this work only if the language is English? How can I use other languages as well? I checked with 75001 as postal code.

Comment: This is a new question. I already gave you a complete answer to your initial question and also to additional request. each question here should be focused on one, specific issue. So, I think you should accept the answer here and in case you have any additional questions - please ask about each new problem separately.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it enough to interact with that switch initially and set the desired country?

Let me make a few changes to your code, which I explain below, to make it perform better for this task.

1. It is necessary to resolve this depreciation notice: *'DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a [Service](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.service) object'*.
2. You can instantiate the driver, reject cookies, and change the country of delivery only once and not at each iteration.
3. You have to integrate some driver [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) (and not sleeps) to prevent the page from still not loading properly and the script from failing. The "DELAY" parameter you can configure based on the speed of your connection, the heaviness of the page, and the performance of your pc.
4. You asked to change the country of delivery, so just select the corresponding value in the drop-down menu with [Select](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/support_features/select_lists/). You can change the country simply by changing that string.
   However, if you want to enter UK from amazon.co.uk (and it is not already selected) you will have to enter a zip code.

```py
import time as t
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=UA")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=2160x3840')

DELAY = 20  # Number of seconds before timing out


def get_secondly_screenshots(driver, url):

    # got to current url
    driver.get(url)

    now = datetime.now()
    date_time = now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
    sh_url = url.split('?k=')[1]
    print(sh_url, date_time)
    driver.save_screenshot(f'{sh_url}_{date_time}.png')

    print('screenshotted ', url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ['https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=advil', 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=Whitening toothpaste']

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

    # first go to amazon site
    driver.get('https://www.amazon.co.uk')

    # You can reject cookies once instead of each iteration
    try:
        cookie_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sp-cc-rejectall-link"]')))
        cookie_btn.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        raise TimeoutException("Page not yet loaded correctly")

    # You can change delivery country once (even here instead of each iteration)
    WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'nav-global-location-popover-link'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'GLUXCountryList')))

    select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'GLUXCountryList'))

    # select country by value (e.g. 'UK')
    select.select_by_value('IT')

    for url in urls:
        get_secondly_screenshots(driver, url)

    driver.quit()
```

To stay in UK, you will have to comment out the Select part and implement the following code in the main:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ['https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=advil', 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=Whitening toothpaste']

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

    # first go to amazon site
    driver.get('https://www.amazon.co.uk')

    # You can reject cookies once instead of each iteration
    try:
        cookie_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sp-cc-rejectall-link"]')))
        cookie_btn.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        raise TimeoutException("Page not yet loaded correctly")

    # You can change delivery country once (even here instead of each iteration)
    WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'nav-global-location-popover-link'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'GLUXCountryList')))

    select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'GLUXCountryList'))

    # set an UK zipcode to foce UK delivery
    WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "GLUXZipUpdateInput"))).send_keys("E1W 2RG")
    WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "GLUXZipUpdate"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, DELAY).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[aria-labelledby='GLUXZipUpdate-announce']"))).click()

    for url in urls:
        get_secondly_screenshots(driver, url)

    driver.quit()
```

Comment: If I change 'IT' to 'UK', I get "Cannot locate option with value: UK". Did it work for you?

Comment: Do you want to set UK or a different country? It seems that if you point to amazon.co.uk, you have to specify a zip code to point to UK, otherwise for other states just put the abbreviation (e.g. IT). I have modified the answer by incorporating the zip code change code. If you implement the second version of the code you solve the problem.